# How to hook jenkins in bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, githooks, bitbucket-api

I am not able to find how to add hooks of jenkin in bitbucket,
Previously there was a link in bitbucket for hooks but now it is missing

Please help

UPDATE:-
 All the solution that are given on stackoverflow are outdated as bitbucket has change few feature

Answer (score 0):

We use the [Jenkins Bitbucket Webhook](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.nerdwin15.stash-stash-webhook-jenkins/server/overview) and it works well.
It's `for Bitbucket Server 4.0.0 - 4.14.4`

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:** Today (Nov, 2017), this add on is not free, but worth the cost.

Comment: it's not free, you need to pay

Comment: At the time time I posted, it was free. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Under Build triggers there is a checkbox with label "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket" check this box, when changes are pushed to bitbucket it will start a build.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply,
But that I already know, I am asking on bitbucket side.
As for getting event on jenkin you have to register the hook url on bitbucket

Comment: oops.. go to bitbucket and then chose your repo. Then
Settings>webhooks>add webhook.
There you can add a web hook
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html